# Reindex Category

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a problem in reindexing the categories 
when I type

```
php -f shell/indexer.php catalog_category_flat
```

I got this error

```
Usage:  php -f indexer.php -- [options]

  --status <indexer>            Show Indexer(s) Status
  --mode <indexer>              Show Indexer(s) Index Mode
  --mode-realtime <indexer>     Set index mode type "Update on Save"
  --mode-manual <indexer>       Set index mode type "Manual Update"
  --reindex <indexer>           Reindex Data
  info                          Show allowed indexers
  reindexall                    Reindex Data by all indexers
  help                          This help

  <indexer>     Comma separated indexer codes or value "all" for all indexers
```

I have tried with -f and without it

Thanks in advance

Comment: You command should be `php -f shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_flat`

Answer (score 1):

Re-Index Magento 1 from shell

Login to SSH:

```
cd [MAGENTO_ROOT]/shell/
```

Will display current status of indexer:

```
php indexer.php --status
```

Will reindex all data:

```
php indexer.php reindexall
```

If you wish to reindex specific indexer then first run:

```
php indexer.php info
```

It will display all available indexer code

Default indexer codes here:

```
catalog_product_attribute Product Attributes
catalog_product_price Product Prices
catalog_url Catalog Url Rewrites
catalog_product_flat Product Flat Data
catalog_category_flat Category Flat Data
catalog_category_product Category Products
catalogsearch_fulltext Catalog Search Index
cataloginventory_stock Stock Status
```

Here is command to reindex specific indexer:

```
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat
```

Comment: Thanks for this complete answer , that is what I have done

Answer (score 0):

I have forgot --reindex

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_flat
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/175240)

Comment: You mean that I should write the full code ?